# Brownian Motion as Continuous-Time, Continuous State-Space Markov Chain?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, markov-chains, brownian-motion, markov-process

I've been assigned to teach a course going over Markov chains next semester, and I never really feel I understand a topic until I understand "it (the topic) on manifolds".

So, a (homogeneous) Markov chain occurs in discrete-time and has a discrete (finite) state space. Given a state $\vec{v}_k$ with $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n v_{k_i} = 1$, the next state is given by $\vec{v}_{k+1} = \vec{v}_kP$, where $P$ is a (right) stochastic matrix, and, if the matrix $P$ is regular, the system drifts towards the open-loop steady-state vector $\vec{\pi}_{OL}$ with $\vec{\pi}_{OL} = \vec{\pi}_{OL}P$, $\pi_{OL_i} > 0$, and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \pi_{OL_i} = 1$.

A (homogeneous) continuous-time Markov process occurs in continuous time and and has a discrete (finite) state space. Given a state $\vec{v}_t$, there is a random amount of time $T_t$ where the system transitions to the next state and the new state vector is given by $\vec{v}_{t+T_t} = \vec{v}_tP(t+T_t)$ where $P(t+T_t)$ is a (right) stochastic matrix satisfying $P(0) = I$ and $P(t+h) = P(t)P(h)$. Under certain regularity (and homogeneity) conditions, $P(t) = \exp(tJ)$, where $\displaystyle J = \lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} \frac{P(h) - I}{h}$ is a constant jump-rate matrix with $j_{ii} = -\lambda_i$ and $j_{ij} = \lambda_ip_{ij}$ for $i \ne j$, where $\lambda_i > 0$, $p_{ij} > 0$, and $\sum\limits_{j \ne i} p_{ij} = 1$, so each row sums to 0. In general, the system drifts towards the open-loop steady-state vector $\vec{\pi}_{OL}$ with $\vec{\pi}_{OL}J = 0$, $\pi_{OL_i} > 0$, and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \pi_{OL_i} = 1$.

Is it then true that a (homogeneous) continuous-time Markov process with $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a state space is a Brownian motion $B_t$ with (1) $B_t$ everywhere continuous but nowhere differentiable, (2) $B_0 = \vec{0}$, (3) $B_s - B_t\ \coprod\ B_r$ for $r < t < s$, (4) $E\{B_s - B_t\} = \vec{0}$ for $s > t$, and (5) $B_t \sim N(\vec{0}, tI)$? I'm a little fuzzy on the concept of what might be a steady-state vector for Brownian motion on $\mathbb{R}^n$; maybe one needs a matrix $A$, a symmetric matrix $\Sigma$, a solution to a geometric SDE $dX_t=AX_tdt+\Sigma X_tdB_t$, and then $\pi_{OL}$ is the probability measure given by taking the the pdf $\rho$ of $X_0$ and setting $\displaystyle \pi_{OL}(A) = \int\limits_{A} \rho\ d\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure? Additionally, I know there's something about a function satisfying $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \Delta(f)$ (the Laplacian) that comes up around here, but I'm not really to that point yet.

Finally, is it then true that a (homogeneous) continuous-time Markov process with a closed, Riemannian manifold $(Q^n,g)$ as a state space is a Brownian motion on $(Q,*)$ ($*$ is the basepoint of $Q$)? I'm a little fuzzy on the concept of what might be a steady-state vector for Brownian motion on a manifold; maybe one has some sort of vector field $\xi: Q \to TQ$ and mapping $\sigma: Q \to L_{Self-Adjoint}(TQ,TQ)$, a geometric SDE on $Q$, $dX_t = \xi(X_t)dt + \sigma(X_t)[\xi(X_t)]dB_t$, and $\pi_{OL}$ is the probability measure given by taking the the pdf $\rho$ of $X_0$ and setting $\displaystyle \pi_{OL}(A) = \int\limits_A \rho\ d\gamma$, using the the natual Riemannian volume measure space $(Q, \mathcal{B},\gamma)$ on $(Q,g)$ ($\mathcal{B}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets)? Additionally, I know there's something about a function satisfying $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \Delta(f)$ (the Laplace–Beltrami operator) that comes up around here, but I'm not really to that point yet.

**Edit 1**: Per [https://math.unice.fr/~delarue/Vortrag_Nice.pdf](https://math.unice.fr/%7Edelarue/Vortrag_Nice.pdf), a Markov process for a Brownian motion $B_t$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ has $P_h(B_t) = B_{t+h}$. A probability measure $\pi_{OL}$ on the measurable space $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{E})$ ($\mathcal{E}$ is the Lebesgue measurable sets) then might be an *invariant measure* for the Brownian motion $B_t$/Markov process $P_t$ if $\pi_{OL}(A) = \Pr\{P_h(B_t) \in A\} = \Pr\{B_t \in A\}$ for all $t,h>0$ and all $A \in \mathcal{E}$. A similar notion might hold for Brownian motions on manifolds. See http://airvigilante194.sdf.org/mathjax/Markov.html for some sort of exposition or another on how one might "flow" a generic probability distribution $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to an invariant probability distribution $\pi_{OL}$.

**Edit 2**: Per a comment by Chris Janjigian, Brownian motions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ don't have invariant probability measures, but Brownian motions on a closed manifold $Q^n$ do; it is likely that Brownian motions on the tangent bundle $M = TQ$ of $Q$ (my main line of research interest - I'm actually learning this for a class I'm going to teach, though) similarly don't exist. The method of "flowing" a generic probability distribution $\mu$ to an invariant probability distribution $\pi_{OL}$ on a closed manifold $Q$ in the above link should still be valid.

Comment: I guess this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683775/invariant-measures-for-stochastic-processes answere the question about invariant measures: one needs a solution to an SDE $dX_t = bX_tdt + \sigma X_tdB_t$, and then $\pi$ is the measure given by the pdf of $X_0$.

Comment: This is a nice video explaining why $(dB_t)^2 = dt$ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfE4PGVFHnU

Comment: It appears I've kind-of worn out my welcome on SE, so I'll just ask this in a comment: in a geometric Brownian motion SDE $dX_t=bX_tdt+σX_tdBt$ on a manifold with $H_{1,dR}(Q) \ne 0$, is it possible the RHS $bX_tdt+σX_tdBt$ is closed but not exact? I'm not even really sure what those words might mean, I just know there's a similar concern with the "exact ODE" $\displaystyle \frac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dx + \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\ dy$

Comment: I guess because $dt$ time is linear and points separate, that's not possible, for the same reason that every continuous 1D differential form $f(t)dt$ has an antiderivative $F(t)$ with $dF = f(t)dt$.

Comment: Here's a short version. What you call $J$ in the discrete case is the infinitesimal generator of a process. As a tool to define the process, that generalizes to the continuous space-time case by Hille-Yosida. This is worked out in many places and in generality in the text by Ethier and Kurtz.  Brownian Motion is the process on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with infinitesimal generator given by $\frac{1}{2}\Delta$. On a Riemannian manifold, Brownian Motion is the process with infinitesimal generator given by the Laplace-Beltrami operator. See here: https://math.harvard.edu/~ctm/math219/home/sources/hsu.pdf

Comment: Let me recommend the short book "Stochastic Integrals" by H. P. McKean as a potentially useful reference for your needs. In particular, chapter 4 "does it on manifolds".

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Thanks so much for replying!

All this seems a little above my paygrade. I took a look at your link, and I think I understand a little bit now Markov chains on manifolds, now, though; thanks again so much

Comment: @MatthewKvalheim Thanks so much for replying! Chapter 4 does, indeed, "do it on manifolds (continuously but not smoothly)"

Comment: This https://math.unice.fr/~delarue/Vortrag_Nice.pdf appears to provide an answer about invariant measures that has nothing to do with geometric SDEs

Comment: Brownian motion on $\mathbb{R}^d$ does not have an invariant probability measure. This is basically because the the transition probabilities, which are given by the heat kernel, push probability away from any compact set as time increases. In probability language, the family is not tight.  You can see that explicitly by computation. On a compact manifold, Brownian motion will have an invariant measure by Krylov-Bogolioubov.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Thanks so much again for replying! That's an awesome comment. As an amateurish rejoinder, the recurrence time to any compact set $K$ might go to infinity, meaning $\pi_{OL}(K)$ would have to be 0. Super-insightful, thank you