# Limit of solutions to SDEs

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $W_t$ be a Brownian motion defined on some probability space and let $X$ be the (strong) solution to the SDE:

\begin{equation}
    dX_t = b(t, X)dt + \sigma(t, X)dW_t,
\end{equation}
with $X(0) = X_0$. I am interested in the limit (in distribution)

\begin{equation}
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} X_t.
\end{equation}
In particular, I would like to know when it is well-defined and, when it is defined, what its distribution is.

As an example, when $b(t, x) = 0$, $\sigma(t, x) = 1$, the solution is Brownian motion, which does not have a limit in distribution as $t\rightarrow\infty$. However, if instead $b(t, x) = -x$ we have a particular case of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process which has a limiting distribution.

Can anyone recommend a good text which covers this subject?

Comment: Ask google for invariant (or stationary) measure of Ito diffusion processes. Other key words that may be helpful are Langevin dynamics and Fokker-Planck equation.

Comment: Thank you @Tobsn, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with some very complicated process, here are some tools to help you study the growth of the process.

The most comprehensive tool is Feller's test (Shreve-Karatzas theorem 5.29).

[image]

Secondly, one can also use Lyapunov functions as done in ["Stochastic Stability of Differential Equations"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-23280-0). Also see "Solutions of Stochastic Differential Equations obeying the Law of the Iterated Logarithm, with Applications to Financial Markets∗".

Thirdly, if one is looking for invariant measures, you can use the stationary Fokker-Plank eg. [Invariant measures for stochastic processes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683775/invariant-measures-for-stochastic-processes) and ["Long-time dynamics
of stochastic differential equations"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.12998.pdf).