# Convergence of an integral of a stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-differential-equations

I am not a mathematician so I apologize for the sloppy language in advance. I am dealing with a random variable $z(t)=\int_{0}^{t} r(\tau) d\tau$ where $r(t)$ is some hitherto unknown random variable. I want to know the conditions under which the variance of $z(t)$ does not diverge as $t\rightarrow \infty$.

I can think of one example, if $z(t)$ is an OU process, I can show that $r(t)$ is also an OU process with a mean of zero. I also know that if $r(t)$ is a Brownian motion, then the variance of $z(t)$ will diverge with increasing $t$. Is there a general statement I can make?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can express the variance of $z(t)$ as $$\mathrm{Var}(z(t)) = 2\int_0^t \int_0^s \mathrm{Cov}(z(u), z(s)) \mathrm{d}u \mathrm{d}s,$$ so the variance is finite if that integral is finite. For stationary processes one can consider the power spectrum density of the process. Is this along the lines of what you're looking for?

Comment: How do you show that when $z(t)$ is an OU process that $r(t)$ is also an OU process?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways people study the long-time behaviour. As mentioned in the comments, if we can just directly uniformly bound the $L^{2}$ norm, then we have control.

If you are dealing with some very degenerate/complicated process, here are some tools to help you study the growth of the process.

The most comprehensive tool is Feller's test (Shreve-Karatzas theorem 5.29).

[image]

Secondly, one can also use Lyapunov functions as done in ["Stochastic Stability of Differential Equations"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-23280-0). Also see "Solutions of Stochastic Differential Equations obeying the Law of the Iterated Logarithm, with Applications to Financial Markets∗".

Thirdly, if one is looking for invariant measures, you can use the stationary Fokker-Plank eg. [Invariant measures for stochastic processes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683775/invariant-measures-for-stochastic-processes) and ["Long-time dynamics
of stochastic differential equations"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.12998.pdf).